# How to receive messages from the queue once a minute spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

I have a listener

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "QUEUE_NAME")
public void checkStatus(Message message, JmsMessageHeaderAccessor jmsMessageHeaderAccessor) throws Exception {
    // TO DO
}
```

I need to receive a message from the queue once a minute. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a sleep() or use JmsTemplate.receive() instead of a listener.

Comment: can you get example for jmsTemplate.receive()?

Comment: See the [javadocs of `JmsOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/jms/core/JmsOperations.html), specifically the variants of `receive()` and `receiveAndConvert()`. And the [Spring Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms)